# Is it possible to push a specific directory in a git repo to a remote bare repo?

Tags: git

I have a case where I have a repo which contains a number of directories where specific folders are to be pushed to different servers.

One of these directories is to be pushed to the webserver, the rest of the directories are not to be pushed to a webseserver.

I know I could separate out the folders into submodules or subtrees but this is not an option in my case.
I am also familiar with git sparse checkout, but this is not possible to configure on a bare repo as far as I am aware.

On the web server I have a bare repo which I push to like so:
http://toroid.org/git-website-howto

Is there any way for me to push just a specified folder to the bare repo on the webserver?

Comment: Why don't you just add the folders which you don't want in a .gitignore file?

Comment: This is not possible, because commit objects in git contain the full tree. You could reconfigure your web server to only look inside the directory that the public files are in. Alternatively, you could have the different types of content on different branches (which don't share history), but at that point it's almost the same as having different repositories altogether.

Comment: FYI git never commits "folders". Folders are only meta data of where files reside. GIT only stores files. If a folder has no files or those files are ignored, etc, nothing is sent to GIT

Comment: This sounds like a build issue, not a GIT issue. GIT is source control, it's not designed to control what gets deployed where, etc. Use something like Jenkins for that.

Comment: @Vandesh .gitignore is not an option here as the other files still need to be tracked in git.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know git add can be used with a regular expression:

```
patch

    This lets you choose one path out of a status like selection. After choosing the path, it presents the diff between the index and the working tree file and asks you if you want to stage the change of each hunk. You can select one of the following options and type return:

    y - stage this hunk
    n - do not stage this hunk
    q - quit; do not stage this hunk or any of the remaining ones
    a - stage this hunk and all later hunks in the file
    d - do not stage this hunk or any of the later hunks in the file
    g - select a hunk to go to
    / - search for a hunk matching the given regex
    j - leave this hunk undecided, see next undecided hunk
    J - leave this hunk undecided, see next hunk
    k - leave this hunk undecided, see previous undecided hunk
    K - leave this hunk undecided, see previous hunk
    s - split the current hunk into smaller hunks
    e - manually edit the current hunk
    ? - print help

    After deciding the fate for all hunks, if there is any hunk that was chosen, the index is updated with the selected hunks.

    You can omit having to type return here, by setting the configuration variable interactive.singleKey to true.
```

Or you can create separate repos in the subfolder.

If you are in a creative mood, you can also implement the following algorithm:

```
foreach folder in folders
    foreach file in folder
        git add folder/file

execute git commit -m"My commit message"

execute git push remotename branchname
```